# ((always_inline)) does not work when function is implemented in different file

Tags: c, gcc, inline-functions

I have a file `funcs.h` where I have the declaration of function:

```
inline void some_func( void ) __attribute__((always_inline));
```

Then I have a file `funcs.c` where I have the implementation of the function:

```
inline void some_func( void ) { … }
```

Then in my main file `main.c` I `#include` the `funcs.h` and try to use `some_func()` somewhere in the code. However when I compile my program and look at the binary file, the function appears to be compiled as a regular separate function, and called just like any other regular function, instead of being embedded as inline.

Why is that happening, and is there a way to force actual inlining into this? (Except the option of just using `#define` macros instead of functions, of course.)

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to inline a definition that is found after compilation?

Comment: You will have to turn on link-time optimization (`-flto` switch).

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast not the compiler, the linker.

Comment: @user3477950, That's a good point I guess. I remember Microsoft saying something about the optimizations the linker can do.

Comment: @user3477950 simple testing shows that even `a+b` function isn't inlined with gcc 4.8 and `-flto`. Moreover, using this attribute produces compile error, since compiler knows for sure that it can't inline, while programmer insists that it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the implementations is the header.  If they're not available in the translation unit in which you intend to do the inlining, you'll be out of luck.  The linker (well, a *traditional* linker) can't do anything about that for you.

Comment: Most modern toolchains support link-time optimization, relying on that would probably be a better idea that dumping huge pieces of definitions in headers.

Comment: @user3477950: Yes, though relying on compiler optimization makes the `force_inline`-attribute superfluous.

Comment: @Deduplicator …which tells me that one should probably leave low-level optimizations to the compiler, especially nowadays.

Comment: In header file, in case of C and not C++, it should be `static inline`. `inline` itself does not flag function as non-exportable (but in C++ it does).